# What are the differences between an aggregate operation and a method?

Tags: java-8, default-implementation

..........

well, let me tell you i made some mistakes: the foreach() i was refering to is not an aggregate operation but a method from Iteable. I've changed the title of my question and its content.

My interest is to know if an aggregate operation is implemented by default and Where i can find that implementation.

Comment: If you want to find the source code for the Java 8 API, you can look here:  http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/

Otherwise, your question is a little unclear.

Comment: you should configure your IDE to load the `src.zip` as sources for the JDK, this way you can jump straight into the code from your own code via "open declaration" or similar features.

Comment: i was trying to upload an image to clarify the question but i cant because of my level

Comment: by the way, thanks for commenting on the quetion

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dig into the JDK sources you can always download them [here](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/) as @jbkm suggest. If you have the Oracle JDK installed, there should be `src.zip` file in the installation folder which contains all the public sources. Alternatively you can check the OpenJDK sources online, for example, on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Iterable.java#Iterable.forEach%28java.util.function.Consumer%29). As you can see, the implementation of `forEach` for `Iterable` is quite simple:

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (T t : this) {
        action.accept(t);
    }
}
```

If you're asking about the implementation of `forEach` in the Stream API, it's much more tricky thing as it should evaluate all the previous pipeline steps and perform the operation in parallel for parallel streams. You can start your investigation examining the [`ReferencePipeline`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#ReferencePipeline.forEach%28java.util.function.Consumer%29) class which is the `Stream` implementation in OpenJDK.

Comment: the oracle site literarily says: " The default implementation BEHAVES AS IF:   for (T t : this) { action.accept(t); } ".    I wonder if there is a different code instead of the sample code here or if it is the one you posted above, with the additional line - Objects.requireNonNull(action); - as part of it.

Comment: @user3727894: the documentation simply doesn’t mandate a particular implementation and hence, doesn’t give you a guaranty but just a specified *behavior*. An alternative, compatible implementation would be `iterator().forEachRemaining(action);`